# Advantages of using software framework

Tags: apache-flex, frameworks, cairngorm, puremvc

I was reading these days about large projects implementation in python and Flex, and very often people praise the use of framework (like Cairngorm, PureMVC or others) over traditional OOP coding.

I think i dont really understand the advantage of using FW, which is the strong point over classic programming? how big should be the project in order to use FW? it is intended mainly for web-applications? or can be used for desktop apps as well?

hope, all these doubts dont sound stupid to you, i am not Computer engineer, just electronic, so my knowledge of sw architecture is very limited.

Br

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a framework is not really any different from classic OOP programming.

When you write projects in a similar environment, you will probably see yourself writing a framework (or a set of tools) over and over again.

A framework is really just code reuse - instead of you writing the logic for managing a common task, someone else (or you) has written it already for you to use in your project.

A well designed framework will keep you focused on your task, rather than spending time solving problems that has been solved already.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds clear to me. So basically is generic code that performs common tasks like: process communication, data retrieving, program flow control, events...
it seems something interesting to learn.

Br

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how I see it. Django framework, for instance, is a web framework for Python. Instead of writing your own URL parser or your own form validation code, the framework has it written for you. There are of course times when the framework doesn't suit your needs. But when it does, it'll save you time and raise your code quality.

Answer (score 0):

I would add my 2 cents here, using a framework will also help a better organized collaborative environment too. Your team mates will get to know about the code easily if you are following a standard framework. 
In enterprise applications using framework helps meeting the deadline and better code quiality.

Comment: You can miss deadlines and write shoddy code with frameworks, but, people that read your code will understand it better because of the shared knowledge of a framework.